# Error on creating very very simple app using react-native-camera

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-camera

I recently wanted to create a `react-native` app with camera and started working with `react-native-camera` so I just did this:

```
$ react-native init testApp2
$ npm install --save react-native-camera
$ react-native link react-native-camera
$ react-native run-android
```

After the last line I'm getting weird outputs (below)(I have Android studio installed on my pc and exact errors are created by the Android studio when I go for building apk)

```
Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\node_modules (31ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 2 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.2.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:react-native-camera:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:react-native-camera:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugD8: Program type already present: com.facebook.infer.annotation.FalseOnNull

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\6.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\7.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\8.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\54.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\55.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\56.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\57.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\58.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\60.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\61.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\62.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\63.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\76.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\77.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\78.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\79.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\80.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\84.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\98.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\99.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\100.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\101.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\102.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\103.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\104.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\105.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\106.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\107.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\108.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\109.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\110.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\111.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\112.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\113.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\114.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\115.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\116.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\117.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\118.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\119.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\120.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\121.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\122.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\123.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\124.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\125.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\126.jar, C:\Users\seyye_000\Documents\testApp2\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\127.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
36 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 35 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

I've tried every possible way to play with Android studio to get this error fixed but I'm really tired and don't know what to do next. :\

Here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "testApp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.4",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.4.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

if you know what's wrong with this pleaase tell me, I'm starting to go really crazy...

Because I don't know how to put all my code here I just uploaded it on GitHub, [HERE](https://github.com/zhuge-ei/testApp2) is the link to it.

Comment: Show .gradle files

Comment: @shivam i git-pushed all of the project files to a github repository,the link is in the last line. tnx for helping

Comment: have you tried enabling 'multiDexEnabled ' in your app/build.gradle

Comment: yes and it just gave me another errors and i just could'nt tolerate nomore and decided to go for native modules and not using react-native-camera

but thanks for your helping and sorry that i changed my strategy and did'nt answered here  sooner

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling multiDex

In **app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```